# what is difference between B.S 1.0 VS B.S 1.1 specifications in web services?

Tags: web-services

Could somebody pleasee tell me the difference between WS-I Basic Profile 1.0 and WS-I Basic Profile 1.1?

Comment: http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html#changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [WS-1 Basic Profile Version 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html)

> ### 1.2 Changes from Basic Profile Version 1.0
>
> This specification is derived from the Basic Profile Version 1.0, and
>   incorporates published errata against that specification. The most
>   notable changes are:
>
> - MESSAGE conformance target - Some requirements that had a MESSAGE
>     conformance target in BP1.0 now use a new target, ENVELOPE. This
>     facilitates alternate serialisations of the message, such as that
>     described in the Attachments Profile.
> - SOAP Binding - Requirements relating to the SOAP binding's 
>     serialization of the message have been moved to the Simple SOAP 
>     Binding Profile to facilitate other serializations.